# Website working fine in localhost,but not livesite

Tags: wordpress

My website looks and works fine in the localhost,it worked the first time i put it online except for the header links. I was going to fix it then wordpress updated and then my whole website went up,like my changes was lost and images. So i deleted it an reuploaded and it worked fine again except the header links. then i added the do not update script in wp.config.php

Website was fine,then it updated again but only some images where missing now. I then reuploaded everything again and now it doesn't want to work. I did change the wp_options home and site url to my livesite.

Is there something in my cpanel that saved and cached a file or something that i can clear and delete. I did do the replace all function in the database dump to let the localhost be replaced with my url. Like i said it worked(Front page) except header links which i figured was permalinks,and was about to fix it.

Comment: Have you followed the instruction given in [Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: The fact that a WordPress update broke things raises questions about your configuration. Neither core nor template updates should do that. Did you make the required changes to the WordPress config files to reflect the new URL? It's going to be difficult for us to help with so little information. Also, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowing exactly what you modified in WordPress.

Comment: NO changes were made,i ftp'd my files over. Did the replace function with my database,and edited the wp.config.php file accordingly. It worked before and then it updated ,so i reuploaded worked fine,then it updated again,when i did a reupload yet again not working. NO CHANGES were made. I use a custom css plugin as i did not  learn about child themes yet. Thats why i ask could it be something in the cpanel that is causing this from an update that saved

Comment: @Dev-88 what are the changes you made? Can you listed them?

Comment: @Gunaseelan  Only changed the the header hover colour and paragraph tag to another font,and i think the h1 really very few changes. As this is a testing site for me to learn wordpress. But it worked that's what i don't understand,as i made no changes. Is there another file i should check and maybe change after i ftp everything

Comment: @Dev-88 Moving wordpress site from localhost to server is just not a copy-paste of files work. You need to change some values in the wordpress files. See the link which I posted in my first comment. What error did you get when you see your live site?

Comment: set define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: No error,website is showing,just not showing all of my changes,like a file that might preventing it from showing the changes. I followed this tut http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

Comment: @vel turned it on,but the notices on the webpage doesn't show

Comment: can able to load wp-login.php?

Comment: @vel yip website still showing if that is what u mean

Comment: Try this wordpress plugin for local to server "Search-Replace-DB-master"

Comment: can you post screenshot?

Comment: @vel Not at pc at the moment. THe site is basically completely broken,it looks like it may be a theme issue,as some of the theme buttons are like showing that i removed etc etc. Works 100% on localhost,is there something i can delete in my server that has cached a file

Comment: and also check the cache. if you need ask me.

Comment: @vel What cache should i check,i cleared my browser cache? What i dont understand is that it works on my localhost just fine,i read it could be a corrupted .htaccess perhaps?

Comment: yes. It should be. the default htaccess code is below:  # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: @vel i logged into the website to see whats different from the localhost,and found that my page builder,visual editor and rows,were missing and not correct. What might have cause this do it..

Comment: update the permalinks from settings and check plugins deactivate and active again. dis you install cache plugin